# Flask how to return just a variable for jinja without rendering a new page?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to update the variable "error" to the html based off whatever the error is. Currently the variable passes through, but I have to render a new template which refreshes the inputs the user put into the form, making them start the form all over again. How can I pass a variable through without rendering a new page? This is my code. Basically, it gets user input when they submit the form from html inputs and checks the existing SQLite database if the values exist in there already. If they do, then it assigns the error variable with the string of whatever the error is. At the bottom if at least one value exists in the database then `return render_template(register.html, error=error)` passes to update error in the html. I just want the error element to change or somehow preserve user input when rendering a new template. How do I do this?

```
@app.route("/register", methods=["GET","POST"])
def register():
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("register.html")
    else: 
        username = request.form.get("username")
        email = request.form.get("email")
        password = request.form.get("password")
        password2 = request.form.get("password2")
        if password != password2:
            error = "Passwords do not match"
            return render_template("register.html", error=error)
        userCheck = c.execute("SELECT username FROM logins WHERE username = (?)", (username,)).fetchone()
        emailCheck = c.execute("SELECT email FROM logins WHERE email = (?)", (email,)).fetchone()
        passCheck = c.execute("SELECT password FROM logins WHERE password = (?)", (password,)).fetchone()
        if userCheck is None and emailCheck is None and passCheck is None:
            c.execute("INSERT INTO logins VALUES (null,?,?,?)", (username, email, password))
            conn.commit()
            return redirect("/")
        if userCheck is not None:
            error = "Username already taken"
        elif emailCheck is not None:
            error = "This email is already registered"
        elif passCheck is not None:
            error = "Password already taken"
    return render_template("register.html", error=error)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the username and email variables to the render_template.

```
@app.route("/register", methods=["GET","POST"])
def register():
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("register.html",username="", email="")
    else: 
        username = request.form.get("username")
        email = request.form.get("email")
        password = request.form.get("password")
        password2 = request.form.get("password2")
        if password != password2:
            error = "Passwords do not match"
            return render_template("register.html", error=error, username=username, email=email)
        userCheck = c.execute("SELECT username FROM logins WHERE username = (?)", (username,)).fetchone()
        emailCheck = c.execute("SELECT email FROM logins WHERE email = (?)", (email,)).fetchone()
        passCheck = c.execute("SELECT password FROM logins WHERE password = (?)", (password,)).fetchone()
        if userCheck is None and emailCheck is None and passCheck is None:
            c.execute("INSERT INTO logins VALUES (null,?,?,?)", (username, email, password))
            conn.commit()
            return redirect("/")
        if userCheck is not None:
            error = "Username already taken"
        elif emailCheck is not None:
            error = "This email is already registered"
        elif passCheck is not None:
            error = "Password already taken"
    return render_template("register.html", error=error, username=username, email=email)
```

Then update your html (and similar for email).

```
<input type="text" value="{{ username }}">
```